# Difference between using setContentView with layout resource and a view

Tags: java, android

I always wondered why we pass the layout resource into the setContentView() method, and I am not sure I totally understand what all it does.
All I know is I can pass a layout resource file directly, or simply pass a view after inflating it.

Case 1:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Case 2:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
View activity = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, null);  
setContentView(activity);
```

But what is the difference between the two cases? Are they similar, or does setContentView automatically inflate the layout resource file in Case 1 behind the scene just like I am doing in Case 2?

Answer (score 0):

if you see setContentView structure you will find it

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int resId) {
    ensureSubDecor();
    ViewGroup contentParent = mSubDecor.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    contentParent.removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resId, contentParent);
    mAppCompatWindowCallback.getWrapped().onContentChanged();
}
```

I think there is little difference